# Infinite loop to check time

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, time, infinite-loop

Let's say, for example, I want to make a code that calls `console.log()` something at 8:03 every day. I have tried to code something like that using an infinite loop (in fact it is a function that calls itself every 2 seconds) which checks if

```
timeNow is >= timeToConsoleLog
```

and calls `console.log()` when the condition is satisfied, then increments `timeToConsoleLog`.

The code works but I find it very ugly way, I want some advice on how I can implement such a thing in a more beautiful way.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just set an interval for every 24 hours with `setInterval`?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn you still need to find the first 08:03 to start the interval and there are services like Heroku which restart your app once in 24hours so interval would not work

Comment: Euh, It was an example, in reality, the interval changes after every time, I thought about making a dynamic setTimeout (calculating the delta till next event) but I'm not sure it is really good. So, I preferred to ask to see what are my other options.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`node-schedule` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) which lets you schedule events in cron-style.

Running a function once at 08:03 would look like this:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

schedule.scheduleJob('8 3 * * *', yourFunction) // run every day at 08:03
```

the syntax is as follows:

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

Comment: According to your syntax table the parameters to the `scheduleJob` should be `3 8 * * *`

Answer (score 0):

node-cron can help here:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('8 3 * * *', function(){
  console.log('8:03 everyday.');
});
```

More here: https://hackernoon.com/nodejs-javascript-cron-cron-jobs-cronjob-reactjs-scheduler-schedule-example-tutorial-25bcbe23bc6b

Answer (score 0):

You just have to time the first interval, the rest is easy:

```
const DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

function sheduleAt(time, fn) {
  const dayBegin = new Date();
  dayBegin.setHours(0);
  dayBegin.setMinutes(0);
  const left = (dayBegin + time - Date.now()) % DAY;
  setTimeout(function next() {
    fn();
    setTimeout(next, DAY);
  }, left);
}
```

Which can be used at:

```
 sheduleAt(12/*h*/ * 60 + 30/*min*/, () => console.log("lunch"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need calculate timeout to next time when function must been called.

```
        function callFoo(){
            var dateNow  = new Date(),
                nextDate = new Date(),
                timeout  = 0;

            nextDate.setHours(8);
            nextDate.setMinutes(3);

            if(dateNow > nextDate){
                nextDate = new Date(new Date(nextDate).getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
            }

            setTimeout(foo, (nextDate - dateNow));
        }

        function foo(){
            callFoo();
            console.log('It\'s time...');
        }

        callFoo();
```